# I have an issue with making an array function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, shopping-cart

I made this simple shopping cart where you select quantity from a dropwdown list and these numbers get added and you get a total number for all the products and a total number for the product itself.

But i want it write the quantity with price and the name and write it in a div placed on the site so that it is easy for the user to see that he added a product. I made the calculating part by adding the products one by one, as i did not array them. But for this next part i just didn't find a way that suited my needs. This is just from my test page , so i only have a few values , but in the other page i have over 70 listed just like these:

```
<div id="radioAlert">
<script type="text/javascript">
//calculator
function updatesum() {
document.form.sum.value =
(document.form.sum0.value -0) *99 +
(document.form.sum1.value -0) *99 +
(document.form.sum2.value -0) *99;

document.form.smu.value =
(document.form.prod0.value -0)*99  +
(document.form.prod1.value -0) *99 +
(document.form.prod2.value -0) *99 +
(document.form.prod3.value -0) *99 +
(document.form.prod4.value -0) *99;
document.form.totalsum.value =
(document.form.sum.value -0) +
(document.form.smu.value -0); //not a typo i was just lazy with the name

//arrays

//This one i did not get to work.
var myArray = newArray();
myArray[0]=document.form.sum2.value;
myArray[1]=document.form.prod0.value;
myArray[2]=document.form.prod1.value;
myArray[3]=document.form.prod2.value;
myArray[4]=document.form.prod3.value;
myArray[5]=document.form.prod4.value;

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        alert(myArray[i]);
}


//this part works but i want it to add its value only once and then replace its value if its updated again, if its 0 i want it to be completely removed.

var prod1 = document.form.sum2.value;
var prod2 = document.form.sum1.value;

var radioAlert = document.getElementById("radioAlert");
var radioAlert2 = document.getElementById("radioAlert"); 

if  (document.form.sum2.value>0) {
//document.write("pilotjakke pelsforet small  " +   prod1 + "  stk");
radioAlert.innerHTML += ("pilotjakke pelsforet small  " +   prod1 + "  stk");
alert("pilotjakke pelsforet medium  " +   prod1 + "  stk");
}

if  (document.form.sum1.value>0) {
//document.write("pilotjakke pelsforet small  " +   prod1 + "  stk");
radioAlert2.innerHTML += ("pilotjakke pelsforet medium  " +   prod2 + "  stk");

}
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking, can you clearly state the problem you are having somewhere in the question?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.
if you select "product 1" and select a number from the dropdown list ,i want it to be written on the page"product1 small(quantity)"

The way ive managed so far only works for a one variable and it either overwrites the previous statement which is ok, but when i have a second variable in there they overwrite eachother, either that or it adds indefinetly, so i want to make an array so that this works for multiple variables(e.g prod1,prod2...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `newArray` function in JavaScript by default.

Change

```
var myArray = newArray();
```

to

```
var myArray = [];
```

or

```
var myArray = new Array();
// Note space ---^
```

The form using `[]` is generally preferred. In addition to being more concise, it's not susceptible to someone redefining the `Array` constructor function.

Note that you can initialize the array with the elements as well if you like:

```
var myArray = [
    document.form.sum2.value,
    document.form.prod0.value,
    document.form.prod1.value,
    document.form.prod2.value,
    document.form.prod3.value,
    document.form.prod4.value
];
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sence! but i still have a problem with that loop that checks for everytime the value is over or equal to one that it writes something to a specific place. Nothing is happening when im using 
<code>
for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
{
document.write(myArray[i] + "<br>");
}
</code>

Comment: @Tommy: That code for looping through the array is fine, provided you declare `i` somewhere. Note that you can't use `document.write` after the page is loaded (it does an implicit `document.open` which wipes out all of the content on the page).

Comment: Crowder Silly question, but where/how would i declare the 'i' ?
and yeah ill use innerHTML instead, but weird enough some of the scripts i've tried the document.write actually works on the page :s

Comment: @Tommy: Declare `i` within the function where you use it, via `var i`. For more about why that's important, see my blog post [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Re `document.write`, as long as it's used during page load, not after, it will mostly work as you expect. Best to avoid it, though.

Comment: Still not getting it to work :/
is it something wrong with this part or is it somewhere else? (i tried the Alert command without that working) 

`var radioAlert = document.getElementById("radioAlert"); 
var i;
var myArray = [
    document.form.sum2.value, 
    document.form.prod0.value, 
    document.form.prod1.value, 
    document.form.prod2.value, 
    document.form.prod3.value, 
    document.form.prod4.value 
];

for (i=0; i < myArray.length;i++);
{
radioAlert.innerHTML = (myArray[i] + "<br>");
}
`

Comment: @Tommy: Yes, there shouldn't be a `;` between `for (i=0; i < myArray.length;i++)` and the `{` that introduces the block that's meant to be the body of the loop. It may be worth stepping back from your current task and working through some introductory JavaScript material.

Comment: Crowder, thanks for the help man, i've looked through various of javascript materials and i've gotten a broader understanding of it and i finally got this to work with a lot of tweaking and testing around :)